# Generalising my query to run on all data instead of specific id

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a specific query, that works when I hardcode the ID it should run for. I would like to run it for all IDs in my database.

This is a representative setup:

```
CREATE TABLE `dummy` (
    `total` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `a_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `month` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL
);

Data:

total | a_id | month
2     | 1    | 3
4     | 1    | 5
3     | 1    | 6
6     | 1    | 9
3     | 2    | 4
6     | 2    | 10


CREATE TABLE `months` (
    `month` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL
);

Data: Just the values 1 through 12
```

What I want to achieve is to use the `month` as a timestamp, and for each `a_id` get their total for that month, with **zero** for the months that aren't set up (but **only** between the first month, and the last month, of that `a_id`).

My query so far:

```
SELECT c.month, COALESCE(d.total, 0) AS 'total', COALESCE(d.a_id, 1) AS 'a_id'
FROM (
    SELECT month
    FROM months
    WHERE month >= (SELECT MIN(month) FROM dummy WHERE a_id = 1)
    AND month <= (SELECT MAX(month) FROM dummy WHERE a_id = 1)
) c
LEFT outer JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM dummy
    WHERE a_id = 1
) d ON d.month = c.month
ORDER BY c.month;
```

And its output:

```
month | total | a_id
3     | 2     | 1
4     | 0     | 1
5     | 4     | 1
6     | 3     | 1
7     | 0     | 1
8     | 0     | 1
9     | 6     | 1
```

How can I change this query and get the output for *every* `a_id` in the table, without an external program like PHP change the ID every time?

Comment: @Akina because a_id of 1 only goes between its min and max, so 3 and 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need

```sql
SELECT months.month, 
       COALESCE(dummy.total, 0) total, 
       a_ids.a_id
FROM months
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT a_id
             FROM dummy ) a_ids
LEFT JOIN dummy ON months.month = dummy.month
               AND a_ids.a_id = dummy.a_id
INNER JOIN ( SELECT MIN(month) min_month,
                    MAX(month) max_month
             FROM dummy ) borders ON months.month BETWEEN borders.min_month 
                                                      AND borders.max_month
ORDER BY a_ids.a_id, months.month;
```

or

```sql
SELECT months.month, 
       COALESCE(dummy.total, 0) total, 
       a_ids.a_id
FROM months
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT a_id
             FROM dummy ) a_ids
LEFT JOIN dummy ON months.month = dummy.month
               AND a_ids.a_id = dummy.a_id
INNER JOIN ( SELECT MIN(month) min_month,
                    MAX(month) max_month,
                    a_id
             FROM dummy
             GROUP BY a_id ) borders ON months.month BETWEEN borders.min_month 
                                                         AND borders.max_month
                                    AND a_ids.a_id = borders.a_id
ORDER BY a_ids.a_id, months.month;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=97ce5caaaf899ba3136adec9fd45770b)

Comment: It's the second solution that works for my case (with 3-9 and 4-10). Thanks! I couldn't get my joins correct to get what I wanted, but you've rewritten all the things to get the same result, and it's even clearer.

Comment: @Tominator In most cases, adapting an existing solution is more expensive than creating a new one.